# Returning Dataset using DBFactory and Oracle Stored Procedure sys ref cusror

Tags: asp.net, oracle, enterprise-library, data-access-layer, odp.net

I'm trying to return dataset from oracle ref cursor using ODP.NET provider and DBFactory.
I'm getting following error when i call this function:

```
Invalid parameter binding
Parameter name: io_cursor
```

code:

```
Dim dbManager As DBManager = New DBManager(ORACONN)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()

        Dim cmd As DbCommand = dbManager.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "SP_NAME"

        Dim param As DbParameter = cmd.CreateParameter()
        param.ParameterName = "io_cursor"
        param.Value = Nothing
        param.DbType = DbType.Object
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        Dim da = dbManager.CreateDataAdaptor()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds)
        Return ds
```

What am i missing here? Will DbType.Object work for OracleDbType.RefCursor type?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think using DbType.Object will work. I think you should be using OracleDbType.RefCursor instead.

[Documentation and example (C#)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featRefCursor.htm#CJAGGEIJ)

Comment: Thanks and yes i know that, I'm creating a data access layer independent of provider. And you cannot set param.DBType to Refcursor.